# Python: Filter in tuples

Tags: python, filter, tuples

I have two lists of tuples. I want a  new list with every member of l2 and every member of l1 that does not begin with the same  element from l2.

I used a for loop and my output is ok.

My question is: How can I use the filter function or a list  comprehension?

```
def ov(l1, l2):

    l3=l1.copy()    
    for i in l2:

        for j in l1:

            if i[0]==j[0]:
                l3.pop(l3.index(j))

    print (l3+l2)            

ov([('c','d'),('c','e'),('a','b'),('a', 'd')], [('a','c'),('b','d')])
```

The output is:

```
[('c', 'd'), ('c', 'e'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]
```

Comment: I can't test but I'm getting alarm bells ringing at `index`  and `pop` in a `for` loop. Does this reliably work across other examples?

Comment: If I understood correctly, this could easily be solved by using (ordered) dictionaries: `d = dict(l1); d.update(l2)`. If necessary, you can convert the dictionary back to a list of tuples.

Comment: @roganjosh I appreciate your alert. I tried with some other examples and works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should be the straight forward solution:

```
>>> l1 = [('c','d'),('c','e'),('a','b'),('a', 'd')]                                                                               
>>> l2 = [('a','c'),('b','d')]                                                                                                    
>>>                                                                                                                               
>>> starters = set(x for x, _ in l2)                                                                                              
>>> [(x, y) for x, y in l1 if x not in starters] + l2                                                                             
[('c', 'd'), ('c', 'e'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]
```

This can be generalized to work with longer tuples with [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

```
>>> starters = set(head for head, *_ in l2)                                                                                             
>>> [(head, *tail) for head, *tail in l1 if head not in starters] + l2                                                            
[('c', 'd'), ('c', 'e'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]
```

Comment: Please can you explain better the meaning of `x for x, _ in l2`?

Comment: @PedroPinto It's tuple unpacking. I could have written `set(x for x, y in l2)` but `_` is used by convention to indicate "this name is not going to be used".

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using `filter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

f = itemgetter(0)
zval = set(map(itemgetter(0), l2))

list(filter(lambda tup: f(tup) not in zval, l1)) + l2

[('c', 'd'), ('c', 'e'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]
```

Or:

```
def parser(tup):
    return f(tup) not in zval

list(filter(parser, l1)) + l2

[('c', 'd'), ('c', 'e'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd')]
```

Comment: I suggest `f = itemgetter(0) ` as the first line and then use `f` throughout.

Answer (score 0):

Filter is a function which returns a list for all True returns of a function, being used as `filter(function(), iterator)`.

```
def compare(one, two):
    for i in two:
        if i[0]==one[0]:
            print("yes:", one,two)
            return False
    return True

l1 = [('c','d'),('c','e'),('a','b'),('a', 'd')]
l2 = [('a','c'),('b','d')]

one_liner = lambda n: compare(l1[n], l2)  # where n is the tuple in the first list
lets_filter = list(filter(one_liner, range(len(l1))))

final_list = l2.copy()
for i in lets_filter:
    final_list.append(l1[i])

print(final_list)
```

I made this as a way to do it. Lambda might be a bit confusing, alert if you don't understand it, and I'll remake it.

List comprehension is a "ternary operator", if you're familiar with those, in order to make a list in a one-liner.

```
l1 = [('c','d'),('c','e'),('a','b'),('a', 'd')]
l2 = [('a','c'),('b','d')]

l3 = [l1[n] for n in range(len(l1)) if l1[n][0] not in [l2[i][0] for i in range(len(l2))]]+l2
print(l3)
```

This code does the trick, but is overwhelming at first. Let me explain what it does. 
`l1[n] for n in range(len(l1)` goes through all the pairs in l1, in order to see if we can add them. This is done when the if returns True.
`l1[n][0] not in` takes the first item, and returns True if doesn't exist in any of the elements of the following list.
`[l2[i][0] for i in range(len(l2))]` makes a list from all the first elements of l2. 
`+l2` is added, as requested.

As a bonus, I'm going to explain how to use else in the same scenario, in case you wanted another result.

```
l1 = [('c','d'),('a','b'),('c','e'),('a', 'd')]
l2 = [('a','c'),('b','d')]

l3 = [l1[n] if l1[n][0] not in [l2[i][0] for i in range(len(l2))] else ("not", "you") for n in range(len(l1))]+l2
print(l3)
```

As you can see, I had to switch the order of the operators, but works as it should, adding them in the correct order of l1 (which I changed for the sake of showing).

[image: Python script]

Comment: why use `range(len())` when you can just use tuple unpacking in the comprehension?

Comment: Old habit from C, honestly. Nevertheless, it's a lower level, and makes beginner-coders understand how lists work. In practice I would also use unpacking.

Comment: you have `('not', 'you')` in your final output and I would also argue that your way is not beginner friendly since it is less readable

Comment: A deeper level of understanding is always better for a beginner, as it avoids problems later on. I've explained what all the pieces of code do, and can rephrase them if they are unclear for the reader. What do you mean with ("not", "you")?

Comment: look at the output you posted in your image

Comment: Yes, @aws_apprentice , that's the intention. Have you read the post?

Comment: have you? the picture you posted of your output does not match the expected output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186241/discussion-between-mazunki-and-aws-apprentice).